# Can we use two Cloud Providers in same terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, terraform, devops, linode

Can i give load balancer DNS name to linode domain as a CNAME record set through a single terraform code?

The load balancer gets created and the obtained DNS name should be added to Linode domain as a record set.Whenever i delete and create this load balancer, the DNS should be added to linode domain as a record set,because every time with new creation the lb DNS name gets changed. Two providers in one TF code, is this possible?

Is there any possible way to make this happen with a code?

Comment: yes, you can use multiple cloud providers in TF with single file and also perform action whenever DNS name changed, record set added to linode.

Comment: For multiple configurations you can visit : https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html, however code would be simple just mention provider in resources.

Answer (score 2):

> Two providers in one tf code ,is this possible? Is there any possible way to make this happen with a code?

Yes, you can use multiple providers in one tf file. To use same provider with different settings (e.g. different credentials) you can use [alias](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#alias-multiple-provider-configurations) attribute:

> You can optionally define multiple configurations for the same provider, and **select which one to use on a per-resource or per-module basis**.

But if the providers are different, e.g. `aws` and `linode`, then you just create both of them in one file:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

provider "linode" {
  token = "$LINODE_TOKEN"
}
```